# After updating Node.js and Socket.io, connections of Socket.io are now frequently disconnected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My service has been updated to Node.js v6.9.4, and the connection of Socket.io is now disconnected frequently.
It was not reproduced in the development environment and decided to recover by returning to the state before updating.

Is this problem only with certain versions?
Will updating to the latest Node.js solve the problem?

Thank you for your cooperation.

- Update version

  ```
  node.js@6.1.0 → 6.9.4  
  socket.io@1.4.6 → 1.7.2  # Client and server are the same version
  express@4.13.4 → 4.14.0  
  body-parser@1.15.1 → 1.15.2   
  jquery@2.2.3 → 3.1.1  
  jsdom@9.0.0 → 9.9.1
  ```
- State at disconnection

  - The number of connections is about 200.
    (The number of connections before updating is about 20,000.)
  - After 1 or 2 hours of reconnecting, the connection was disconnected.
  - There was no abnormality in CPU load and memory usage of Node.js server and load balancer (Pound).
  - About the log of the browser (devtools)
    The response time of the request (polling) before disconnection was 85 sec, and "400 Bad request" error was output in the next request.
    (The response time in the normal state is 25 sec)

    ```
    GET  https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        200 OK  24.99ms  
    POST https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        200 OK  1ms  
    GET https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..         200 OK  25.01ms  
    POST https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        200 OK  0ms  
    GET  https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        200 OK  1m 25s 
    POST https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        400 Bad Request..  
    ------ detail ------  
    NetworkError : 400 Bad Request - https://myapp.com/socket.io.......  
    --------------  
    POST https://myapp.com/socket.io/?node...sport=polling..        400 Bad Request..  
    ------ detail ------  
    NetworkError : 400 Bad Request - https://myapp.com/socket.io.......  
    --------------
    ```
  - About server log
    There was no clue in the log of Node.js.
    The following error was output to the Pound log, but the causal relation is unknown.

    ```
    pound: (7f8592ce7700) e501 bad request "HQ" from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  
    pound: (7f84cdbe5700) BackEnd yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:9443 dead (killed)  
        * "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" or "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy" is the IP address.
    ```
- Infrastructure information

  ```
  Browser ─[ HTTPS ]─ Load balancer(Pound) ─[ HTTP ]─┬─  Node.js Server 1
                                                     ├─  Node.js Server 2
                                                     ├─  Node.js Server 3
                                                     └─  Node.js Server 4
  ```

  - The connection between the browser and the Node server is maintained by polling. (Not WebSocket)
  - The Node application sends an HTTP request to another server
  - Load Balancer

    - OS: CentOS 6.6
    - Middleware for load balancing: pound ver.2.6
    - OS setting change point:

      - Set the maximum number of usable processes to 100,000.
      - Set the limit number of file descriptors to 100,000.
      - Set memory map limit of pthread to 200,000.
      - Set the maximum number of threads to 100,000.
  - Node.js Server

    - OS: CentOS 6.6
    - OS setting change point:

      - Set the limit number of file descriptor to 100,000
- Connecting code

  - Server Code

    ```
    var socketApp = express();
    ...
    var server = new serverBuilder({protcol: 'http', port: 9999}).getInstance(socketApp).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 9999,     function(){
    });

    var io = socketio.listen(server, {cookie: false});

    io.use(function(socket, callback){
      try {
        var hndReq = null;

        if (socket.handshake) {
          hndReq = socket.handshake;
        }

        if (!socket.handshake.query.param1) {
          socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
          return;
        }
        .....
        callback();
    });

    io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
      try {
        var hndReq = null;

        if (socket.handshake) {
          hndReq = socket.handshake;
        }

        socket.on("disconnect", function () {
          ....
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
      }
    });
    ```
  - Client Code

    ```
    var query = 'param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2;
    var socket =  options.io.connect('https://myapp.com/socket.io/', {query:query, 'forceNew':true, reconnect:false});

    socket.on("connect", function (data) {
      self._connected();
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function (client) {
      socket.disconnect();
      self._disconnected();
    });
    ```

Comment: Are you sure you are using matching client and server versions of socket.io?  If you look at the network tab in the client debugger, what exactly do you see happening when the client tries to connect?  What version of socket.io on client?  What version of socket.io on server?  Can you share the connecting code for both client and server?

Comment: @jfriend00 I added content. please confirm.